# Kali Linux official repositories (ca.mirror.babylon.network)

Tags: linux

Is http://ca.mirror.babylon.network/Kali Kali-rolling/main an official Kali repository?

Answer (score 1):

There's only one **official** Kali repo (per **[this official page](http://docs.kali.org/general-use/kali-linux-sources-list-repositories)**):

#### The Kali Rolling Repository

kali-rolling is our current active repository since the release of Kali 2016.1. Kali Rolling users are expected to have the following entries in their sources.list:

> `deb http://http.kali.org/kali kali-rolling main contrib non-free`
> `# For source package access, uncomment the following line`
> `# deb-src http://http.kali.org/kali kali-rolling main contrib non-free`

**Any additional repositories added to the Kali sources.list file will most likely BREAK YOUR KALI LINUX INSTALL.**

I don't see anything mentioning that mirror - and I wouldn't use it in any case.